# Serve http responses whenever it arrives

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Pretty new to web dev so my apologies if it's not very clear.
I have an image processor in my backend that takes varied amount of time to process an image depending on its size, type etc. The number of images that can be sent is anything. I am trying to send multiple images into their api calls from my front end so that all images can be processed in parallel.

Now on my front end side I don't want to wait for the final response, but instead serve any response that my backend sends back (let's say backend got 5 images and processes the 4th image first. I want to show the 4th image anyway and continue showing images as and when they arrive)

I have tried promise.all() but i still have to wait until all images have been processed. Is there any other method that can help?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use await instead of promise and it should work fine